# MS AJAX call on pageUnload

Tags: web-services, asp.net-ajax, page-lifecycle

I have a legacy WebService referenced in a ScriptManager

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   <Services>
         <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/AJAX_SERVICE.asmx" />
   </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And defined like

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
Public Class CAjaxService : Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

   <WebMethod(enableSession:=True)> _
    Public Sub SomeMethod()
         ...
    End Sub

    ...
End Class
```

After that to call the method from JavaScript client code I can simple do

```
CAjaxService.SomeMethod()
```

I need to execute this call when user navigates away from the current page, so I placed it into page unload event:

```
function pageUnload(sender, args) {
   CAjaxService.SomeMethod()
}
```

The problem is - the call is async and page navigates away before call is complete (if I place `alert()` after the call - it goes thru). I've seen similar problems with jQuery ajax calls (and recommended solution to make a synchronous call) but I am not sure if this is possible in MS Ajax.

What would be the way to execute (and complete) an AJAX call upon user navigating away from current page?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement completely. If you want page to be navigated after ajax call is complete you can check response status & navigate only when there is success/Error in response.

Comment: I cannot predict all the ways page is going to unload (user clicks a link, user types a url, user simple closes the page etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own function

```
CAjaxService.SomeMethodSync = function() {
   ...
}
```

where I do a manual synchronous post request. Not the most elegant method, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach to the `onBeforeUnload` event instead of the `onUnload` event.

The `onUnload` event actually fires when the first byte of the next page is downloaded.  At this time the entire context of the previous page starts to get destroyed, and there's a very low chance that you will be able to create network connections.  The best that you could do at this point is set a cookie via JavaScript.

The `onBeforeUnload` event, however, fires before the request for the next page is made, and you have enough time to make a network call to your server to pass it some information.  Make your Ajax call within this method.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I don't think it will be 100% reliable. Navigation still could happen before request is complete

Comment: we use this pretty reliably in boomerang serving hundreds of millions of requests daily.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reply your requirements I create a simple web service that sleep for 5 seconds

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[ScriptService]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class CAjaxService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {


    [WebMethod(true)]
    public string SomeMethod() {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

}
```

I try to call it synchronusly but the only way to do it using the MS Ajax Library is to extends the Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor you can see the [post](http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/synchronous-page-method-call-in-asp-net-ajax-library/)

I can make the page to wait in the unload event using jquery and make the ajax call synchronously with this code

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script>
       window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CAjaxService.asmx/SomeMethod",
                async: false,
            });
        };
    </script>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Yup I am aware that you can make sync AJAX call with jQuery. Unfortunately this project doesn't use jQuery. I could also make a sync call with a standard XMLHttpRequest, but that defiec MS Ajax paradigm. But that link you found sounds promising, I am going to read thru it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok now I understand your requirements, so I think the best way is to extend the Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor to make the synchronus call